# Using Selenium inside a class

Tags: python

I'm not very experience with writing classes and somewhat confused by their behavior.

`test.py`

```
class Profile:
  def __init__(self):
    self.browser = webdriver.Chrome()
  def browser_object(self):
    return webdriver.Chrome()
```

from the terminal:

```
from test import Profile
# I thought this would initialize webdriver.Chrome() and a browser window would pop up

x = Profile.browser_object()
# trying to access the webdriver so I can do something like

x.get(url) #from the terminal
```

No browser window is popping up. When I run `x` I see that it is a `<function Profile.browser_object ...>`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The code you posted doesn't do what you say it does. It crashes at `Profile.browser_object()` because of the missing `self` parameter.

Comment: By the way, your class doesn't look very useful. I'm fairly sure you'd be better off without it. Also, why would importing a class create an instance of it? It looks like the import system is another thing you don't understand. Please read a tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your other script to actually make an instance of the class you defined in `test.py`.

```
from test import Profile
profile_instance = Profile() # make an instance
browser_I_made = profile_instance.browser_object() # you probably wouldn't do this, but it's possible
```

I don't think you understand that a class is like a factory and you get "instances" of that object off the assembly line like in `profile_instance = Profile()`